# how to use Sub-processes in Activity Diagram / UML for APP

Tags: subprocess, uml, activity-diagram

I am currently working on an activity diagram to represent the verification process.
The whole process is divided into several sub-processes.

**Sub-process 1:** *The process begins with checking the completeness of the information in the registration form. If any information is missing, the customer is returned to the new entry.*

If the information is complete, three partial sub-processes are initiated and executed simultaneously.

**Sub-process 2:** *Checking whether consent to the GTC has been given. This is done directly in the system by
testing whether the corresponding field in the registration form is ticked.*

**Sub-process 3:** *The bank details are checked by sending a request to the bank specified by the customer.
Subsequently, a maximum of 2 weeks is also waited for the bank's reply.
with the result of whether the bank details are correct or not. Here, too, the events: Timeout and Abort can occur and end the process with a negative result.*

**Sub-process 4:** *The Post procedure for identity verification is initiated by generating a verification code and sending it to the customer by email.
After sending, the sub-process waits for one of three events to occur:
The customer has 2 weeks to complete the form and prove their identity by presenting their ID at a post office or via video with the post office. The post office will then send a response to the head office with the result of the verification (pos./neg.). Timeout: If the head office does not receive a response from the post office within 2 weeks, the process is terminated with a negative outcome. Break: also leads to a negative result.*

The overall process is positively completed when all sub-processes have been positively completed.
If a sub-process is negative, other sub-processes that may be waiting are aborted by executing an action: "Abort waiting processes". These processes then leave their interruptable regions" via the path Abort. The customer then receives a notification about the negative outcome of the verification and the entire process is ended with a negative outcome.

This is my activity-diagram:

[image: identity check]

My questions are:

1. The model works with several termination options. Both at the post office and at the bank, you have 2 weeks to react and only when both are available plus the general terms and conditions, the ID check is complete. How do I show that all processes have to be completed before you get to the final state ?
2. Which process (1-4) looks okay, which not ?

Comment: This has so many flaws that as a tutor I would reject it completely :-/ Maybe you can come up with a question content boiled down to your actual question.

Comment: How do I show that all processes have to be completed before you get to the final state?

Comment: What other mistakes do you see? If I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I can't improve it.

Comment: Which process (1-4) looks okay, which not ?

Comment: You could boil that down to: I have 2 parallel processes which both need to be completed before it continues. And that is answered by using a fork.

Comment: @qwerty_so: Yes the post and bank process. I have updated my UML model. And adjusted my questions accordingly.

Comment: Basically it's ok. I would move the timer out to the outer region and handle a common 2-week timeout right from there (with exception to some outside handler).

Answer (score 1):

I abbreviated the flow to simplify it. But basically I would have come up with this:

[image]

If Register and the two Check actions complete it will run to the ActivityFinal. And if for some reason two weeks gone by with not all of them completing the timer would fire and continue with the Cancel action.

This is not much different to yours except the register might take ages. From a business perspective I would put a focus on that and discuss with stakeholder. However, if they insist on leaving it that way, that action could be moved outside the region and only the two checks would lead to a premature cancellation.

[image]